# Задать уникальный id для запроса, и в зависимости от параметров делать reject

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Необходимо задать уникальный идентификатор для запроса(на стороне сервера), и если раньше был такой же(с таким же айди и параметрами от того же юзера) отклонять выполнение запрос до того момента пока он не выполнится. Как это правильно осуществить?

Comment: Зависит от того, зачем вам это. Хотите избежать дублирования запросов? Или для защиты от запросов со стороны?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хочу избежать дублирования запросов, ибо потом запрос с этим айди с моего бэка будет идти на другой сервер

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ко мне приходит запрос в параметрами, я его разбераю и присваиваю айди, и потом через resttemplate шлю на другой сервер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Spring MVC из коробки есть защита от дублирования неидемпотентных запросов. Не знаю, как это настраивается в Boot, но в XML-конфигурации контекста сервлета можно включить этот функционал так

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="synchronizeOnSession" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Теперь двойной клик на кнопке отправки формы не приведёт к двум срабатываниям контроллера.

**UPDATE:** Если нужно рубить запросы от разных пользователей, но с одинаковым набором данных, то можно зарегистрировать в контексте интерцептор

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private RequestService requestService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if ("GET".equals(request.getMethod()))
            return true;

        if (requestService.inProcessing(request)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            requestService.add(request);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {

        requestService.remove(request);
    }
}
```

и какой-нибудь сервис для отслеживания запросов находящихся в обработке

```
@Service
public class RequestService {
    private final Set<String> requests = new HashSet<>();

    private static String getId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        for (String value : request.getParameterValues()) {
            md.update(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] hash = md.digest();
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);
    }

    public boolean inProcessing(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String requestId = getId(request);
        return requests.contains(requestId);
    }

    public void add(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String requestId = getId(request);
        requests.add(requestId);
    }

    public void remove(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String requestId = getId(request);
        requests.remove(requestId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне надо сгенерировать айдишник на основе полей и запрещать идентичные запросы, пока первый не выполнится

Comment: Даже если это запросы от разных пользователей?

Comment: нет, блокировать одинаковые запросы от одного юзера

Comment: @noxi тогда `synchronizeOnSession` - именно то, что вам надо. Он именно это и делает.

Comment: а можете рассказать что к чему? как это работает?

Comment: Если эта настройка включена, то Spring синхронизирует post-запросы от пользователя. То есть два запроса одновременно выполняться не будут.

Comment: А на @requestbody это будет распространятся, или только на параметры?

Comment: Не проверял, но думаю, что на любые запросы будет распространяться.